# Issue on Collection View performBatchUpdate when animating a height change of an Item

Tags: animation, height, collectionview

There is a problem when using performBatchUpdates method to animate a height change on a CollectionViewCell when this results on new items appearing on-screen that were off-screen before the animation ran. In this case scenario the items initially positioned off-screen appear at their final location instead of being animated there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this workaround to avoid this undesired behavior on this Github page.

The trick is done by changing the height of the CollectionView before running the animation and setting it back to the original value on the completion block  of the performBatchUpdate Method.

This is what the code could look like:

```
frameUpdate.size.height += kExpandedHeight - kCollapsedHeight;
collectionView.frame = frameUpdate;

[collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
     _cells[indexPath.item] = @(newHeight);
 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
     frameUpdate.size.height -= kExpandedHeight - kCollapsedHeight;
     collectionView.frame = frameUpdate;
 }];
```

For a full project sample of this workaround go to the Github page

```
https://github.com/jpsim/UICollectionView-Animation-Bug
```

Thanks for sharing JP Simard!